# How to check statistics targets used by ANALYZE?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

How do I check the current statistics targets used by `ANALYZE`?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The setting for the statistics target is stored per column in the catalog table [`pg_attribute`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-attribute.html). You can set it like this:

```
ALTER TABLE myschama.mytable ALTER mycolumn SET STATISTICS 1234;
```

And check it like this:

```sql
SELECT attstattarget
FROM   pg_attribute
WHERE  attrelid = 'myschama.mytable'::regclass
AND    attname = 'mycolumn';
```

Or you just look at the creation script in the object browser of pgAdmin, where it is appended if the value is distinct from the default in [`default_statistics_target`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-query.html#GUC-DEFAULT-STATISTICS-TARGET).

[The manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-attribute.html) on `attstattarget`:

> `attstattarget` controls the level of detail of statistics accumulated
> for this column by [`ANALYZE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-analyze.html). A zero value indicates that no
> statistics should be collected. **A negative value says to use the
> system default statistics target.** The exact meaning of positive
> values is data type-dependent. For scalar data types, `attstattarget`
> is both the target number of "most common values" to collect, and the
> target number of histogram bins to create.

**Bold** emphasis mine.

Statistics for plain index columns are identical to column statistics and have no separate entries in statistics tables. But Postgres gathers separate statistics for index **expressions**. Those can be tweaked in a similar fashion:

```
ALTER INDEX myschema.myidx ALTER COLUMN 1 SET STATISTICS 1235;
```

In absence of actual column names, ordinal numbers are used to address index columns, which correspond to `pg_attribute.attnum`:

```
SELECT attstattarget
FROM   pg_attribute
WHERE  attrelid = 'myschama.myidx'::regclass
AND    attnum = 1;
```

The setting only actually affects column statistics the next time `ANALYZE` is being run manually or by `autovacuum`.

Answer (score 3):

This provides a cleaner view of current statistics being collected

```
SELECT attrelid::regclass
      ,attname
      ,attstattarget
  FROM pg_attribute 
  WHERE attstattarget >= 0
  ORDER BY attstattarget DESC;
```