# PostgreSQL n_distinct statistics setting

Tags: postgresql, query-planner

Are there multiple ways to set `n_distinct` in PostgreSQL? Both of these seem to be doing the same thing but end up changing a different value within `pg_attribute`. What is the difference between these two commands?

```sql
alter table my_table alter column my_column set (n_distinct = 500);
```

```sql
alter table my_table alter column my_column set statistics 1000;
```

```sql
select
    c.relname,
    a.attname,
    a.attoptions,
    a.attstattarget
from
    pg_class c
    inner join
    pg_attribute a
        on c.oid = a.attrelid
where
    c.relname = 'my_table'
and
    a.attname = 'my_column'
order by
    c.relname,
    a.attname;
```

```
Name         |Value           
-------------|----------------
relname      |my_table       
attname      |my_column         
attoptions   |{n_distinct=500}
attstattarget|1000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Both of these seem to be doing the same thing

Why would you say that? Both commands are obviously distinct. Both are related to column statistics and query planning. But they do very different things.

The statistics target ...

> controls the level of detail of statistics accumulated for this column by `ANALYZE`.  See:

- [Check statistics targets in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15034622/check-statistics-targets-in-postgresql/15034896#15034896)

[Basics in the manual.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/planner-stats.html)

Setting [`n_distinct`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-stats.html) is something completely different. It means hard-coding the number (or ratio) of distinct values to expect for the given column. (But only effective after the next `ANALYZE`.)

Related answer on dba.SE with more on `n_distinct`:

- [Very bad query plan in PostgreSQL 9.6](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/287375/3684)